# Parsing through a Master sheet containing several lists and grabbing the headers of each

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a macro that parses through a Master sheet that contains several lists within it and copying rows from those lists depending on a tag number to a new sheet that corresponds with that tag number. So far, I have been successful in parsing through the various lists and doing that.

Now, I am trying to add the headers from each of those lists to each of the multiple sheets that the rows are being copied to. In this respect, I am having trouble adding to my current macro or even finding a standalone solution for this

In other words, I am trying to grab headers from each of the (multiple) lists in my master sheet and copy them over to the sheets that I am sending rows of data to that corresponds with their tag #.

Below is a (annoyingly long) master sheet example as well as my current macro that parses through that entire sheet and sorts the data depending on the "Load #" column.

Example Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/34SmX.jpg  Sorry for the link, not enough rep to post images :(

Current Macro:

```
Option Explicit

Sub copyPaste_demo()
Dim rowCount, row_ix, temp, i As Integer
Dim TD_COL_IX As Integer
Dim td_value As String
Dim td_values() As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' #################
' Count rows starting in column A
' #################

    rowCount = Worksheets("Master").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
' ########################
' starting row
' ########################
    For row_ix = 1 To rowCount

        temp = isNewTable(CInt(row_ix))
        If temp > 0 Then

            TD_COL_IX = temp

        ElseIf TD_COL_IX > 0 Then

            td_value = Worksheets("Master").Cells(row_ix, TD_COL_IX)
            If Not td_value = "" Then
                td_values = Split(td_value, " ")
                For i = 0 To UBound(td_values)

                    If Not sheetExists("Test Load " & td_values(i)) Then
                    ' #######
                    ' Adds new sheet for each unique identifier underneath 
      "LD   #"
                        Sheets.Add.Name = "Test Load " & td_values(i)
                    End If

                  ' Copy rows to be pasted 
########################################################################### 
TD_COL_IX -1 previously


                    If Worksheets("Test Load " & td_values(i)).Cells(1, 1).Value = "" Then

Worksheets("Master").Range(Worksheets("Master").Cells(row_ix, 1), 
Worksheets("Master").Cells(row_ix, TD_COL_IX)).Copy _
                            Destination:=Worksheets("Test Load " & td_values(i)).Cells(1, 1)
                    Else
                        Dim rowCount_pasteSheet As Integer
                        rowCount_pasteSheet = Worksheets("Test Load " & td_values(i)).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

                        ' Copy rows to be pasted 
########################################################################### 
TD_COL_IX -1 previously


Worksheets("Master").Range(Worksheets("Master").Cells(row_ix, 1), 
Worksheets("Master").Cells(row_ix, TD_COL_IX)).Copy _
                            Destination:=Worksheets("Test Load " & td_values(i)).Cells(rowCount_pasteSheet + 1, 1)
                    End If
                Next i
            End If
        End If
    Next row_ix

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


Function isNewTable(row_ix As Integer) As Integer
Dim colCount, col_ix As Integer

    colCount = Worksheets("Master").Cells(row_ix, 
Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For col_ix = 1 To colCount

        If Not IsError(Worksheets("Master").Cells(row_ix, col_ix).Value) Then
            If Worksheets("Master").Cells(row_ix, col_ix).Value = "LD   #" Then
                isNewTable = col_ix
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next col_ix

    isNewTable = 0
End Function



' ####################################################
' sheetExists(sheetToFind As String) As Boolean
'
' Returns true if the sheet exists, False otherwise
' ####################################################
Public Function sheetExists(sheetToFind As String) As Boolean
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    sheetExists = False
    For Each sheet In Worksheets
        If sheetToFind = sheet.Name Then
            sheetExists = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next sheet
End Function
```

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with? Are able to `debug.print` each desired header value?

Comment: I'm having issues grabbing the entire header for each list and copying them over to the new sheets. I used Macro Recorder (with and without relative references) to try and get it started, but I wasn't successful in making it work past the exact case example I was using. So basically, I am having issues with sticking in those headers in the same time I stick in the data, because it seems much easier to add them as I go than to try and insert cells and add them after the fact

Comment: Not really sure what exactly you mean by "header", but if you are just talking about a cell next to another cell that you can already read out, you should look into the [Range.Offset Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/range-offset-property-excel).

Comment: heading, title, name of column

Comment: For better support on your problem you could provide an example of your data structure

Comment: Being that the list is long and to show the varying list dimensions I've included a screenshot of them in the post. I'm not sure how I'd go about showing it better. Any advice?

Comment: Much better than nothing. What part if this data is now the header, what part is the data, what can you read out, and what not yet?

Comment: The headers are the title of the lists and I also want to bring over the corresponding headings for each column in that list as well. So right now, I can find the "LD #" heading, look through that for an integer value, and add each row that contains a unique tag to a new sheet with a name that corresponds to that number. What I want to do on top of that is, for instance, A row from the "Main Frames" list makes it onto a "Test Load" list, I want to copy and paste the heading of that list onto that "Test Load" sheet before I copy and paste the row with a matching "LD #" to it.

Comment: In other words, I can successfully parse through the "LD #" column to properly break up the data how I want to, but because the lists vary in dimension and structure (in terms of what column headings are where), I havent figured out how to grab the headings of the list to include them into the new "Test Load" sheets that my data is being copied to

Comment: So the "heading" of the "LD #" column would be the string "LD #", right? So the heading is always one row above the first data row?

Comment: yes. the row where that string belongs is what I'd like to copy over to each new sheet that contains something from that list

Comment: So you know that the desired header value is always 1 cell above the first data cell. Did you try to incoorporate my answer below? If yes, update your question with your new code/problem.

Comment: My issue is that the first row below the desired header value doesn't always belong to every sheet. If "LD #" equals 1 in the first row below the headers, then, yes doing an offset and grabbing the headers wouldn't be bad. But what about for load #2 or load #3, if they dont get a tag until the 4th item down, how do I know how far to offset it to properly grab the header line everytime? I can't hardcode values into offset and don't know the variable schema that would work.

Comment: If you don't have a (somewhat) fixed rule on how to find the headers, then you can't program it. You need to identify at least one rule on how to uniquely identify the data you need [e.g. place (offset, most common) or format (special format that is not found elswhere around the cells)]. If you dont have any way to find it logically as in a fixed rule that works every time, you can't program it. It can also be a combination of several factors (e.g. "the value in the 10 cells above this one that is bold").

Comment: If you have around < 20 different headers, you can always hardcode the string values and check, if one of that values occurs somewhere above the values. Short: "search through x cells above the data in each column, copy the value if it matches to this header list".

Comment: yea and then how do I do it so it only gets added once per sheet? gets convoluted quickly :/ lol

Comment: For the only-once-part see my updated answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments: If you are able to access the desired data itself, then you can easily read out the header above that data with the [Range.Offset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/range-offset-property-excel) Property.

### Update:

This pseudocode prevents repetition within a loop

```
Dim headerCopied as Boolean
'for each sheet of data:
'loop for data within the sheet
If headercopied = False Then
'post your code here that you want to run only once per sheet
headerCopied = True
End If
'rest of your code
'next loop cycle
```

Alternatively you can check for something else with that `If` statement, then you won't need the boolean.